# Deploying Artifacts in Nexus for the first time

Tags: maven-2, upload, nexus, artifact

When we try uploading our artifacts for the first time in the nexus repository I get the following error

```
Error retrieving previous build number for artifact 'foo.bar:bar:pom':
repository metadata for: 'snapshot foo.bar:bar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' could 
not be retrieved from repository: InternalSnapshots due to an error: 
Authorization failed: Not authorized.
```

I double checked my nexus username and priveleges and verified them against those that are specified in maven settings.xml and found them to be proper. Is there anything else that I might be missing???

Comment: Even tried using the deployment user (configured by default in Nexus) in settings.xml Stuck with the same error...

Comment: Well...Seems to be some problem with the Nexus security configuration. The problem goes away if I turn the server security off.

Comment: Did you even configure a <server> with <id>, <username> and <password>?